# How may I enhance Django Project Security

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The primary objective is to secure sensitive details within the project by concealing critical information such as `environment variables, hosting details, static` file configurations, and other pertinent data.

I make sure to follow the steps to secure my `Django` applications, let's have a look together

1. Set DEBUG to False in Production

```py
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
```

2. Use a Secret Key from Environment Variables

```py
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', 'default_secret_key')
```

3. Configure Allowed Hosts

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['werexpert.com', '*.werexpert.com']
```

4.Enable HTTPS

```py
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

5. Enable Security Middleware

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # ... other middlewares
]
```

6. 7. Password Validators: Use a variety of password validators to enforce strong password policies

```py
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    # ... other validators
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

7. Database Configuration

- I use a strong username and password and the system change automatically changes database pass and sends to my email

8. Update the Django Version & Secure Static Files

- I use Nginx static file service and avoid `runserver`

9. Logging Configuration, Secure Session Settings, and CSRF Protection

```py
LOGGING = {
    # ...logging configuration
}

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

If you do Implement these all then I'm sure it will significantly enhance the security posture of your Django project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings check *INSTALLED_APPS*:

```
...
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
...
```

And:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

If that didn't help, please, show full `settings.py` file.

Comment: Rudnev Thanks for your kindness. Already I use this system, everything is working but image not working. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Please show full `settings.py`.